# C- how to read input from stdin until newline character using read()?

Tags: c

Basically I want to use the read() function to read in a typed message from STDIN, but I want to quit the message by typing just the enter key instead of using CTRL + D. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: There's a C standard library function to do that - `fgets`. Can you use that or  *must* you use the `read` function for some reason?

Comment: `read` should be used if you want to read block of memory. `read` doesn't care about the contents it's reading. On the other hand what you want to read is a string, `fgets` is the function you should use.

Comment: I guess you would read a character, see if it's a newline, if not then read another character, see if it's a newline, if not then read another character, see if it's a newline, if not then read another character, see if it's a newline, if not then ...

Comment: I'm aware of the fgets function, but my instructor told us to use the read function...

Comment: @immibis I tried something like you said:  int n = 0;
        while (msg[n] != '\n') {
                read(STDIN_FILENO, &msg[n], sizeof(char));
                n += 1;
        }  But this doesn't work.

Comment: @user9367574 You will find out why if you simulate that code on paper. (which can be a useful debugging trick for small programs or snippets)

Comment: @user9367574 that code [belongs in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48818886/edit) as a [short, self-contained, example](http://sscce.org/) that produces the problem you're having. Speaking of the problem you're having, "doesn't work" is only slightly less nebulous than "something isn't right". What *does* it do, and how, exactly, does it differ from your intended goal? That too, belongs in your question.

Comment: @immibis Ok I see one issue with that code, so I switched the lines read(STDIN....); and n += 1. But when I call printf to print out the contents of msg it only gives me the newline character.

Comment: @user9367574 more paper debugging? (what goes in msg[0]?)

Comment: @immibis Thanks for your hints. I got it to work now

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I don't know what teachers are thinking. Instead of teaching how to
use the correct functions properly, they give you assignments where you cannot
use variables, or you cannot return pointers and you cannot even use
functions. For me it's like when the master carpenter tells the young
apprentice *nail this nail, but don't use your hammer, use your screwdriver
instead*. Enough about my rant...

The problem here is that you want to read content that has meaning (newline for
example) with a function that just reads a block of bytes and doesn't care for
the meaning of the bytes. If the newline is in the middle of the block you've
read, then you've read too much. The best way would be to read one byte at a
time and check if it is the newline.

```
int get_from_user(char *buffer, size_t size)
{
    size_t cnt = 0;
    char c;

    if(buffer == NULL || size == 0)
        return 0;

    while(read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1) == 1 && cnt < size - 1)
    {
        if(c == '\n')
        {
            buffer[cnt] = 0;
            return 1;
        }

        buffer[cnt++] = c;
    }

    buffer[cnt] = 0; // making sure it's 0-terminated
    return 1;
}
```

And when you want to read:

```
char line[100];
get_from_user(line, sizeof line);
```

Comment: But shouldn't you read in the size of a single char instead of 1 byte?

Comment: @user9367574 -- in C `sizeof (char)` is 1 byte by definition.

Comment: @DavidBowling of course I meant `buffer[cnt++] = c`, I had a typo I didn't realize.

Comment: @DavidBowling thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer.